# Can't create Wordpress site in Azure - stuck on checkbox for ClearDB

Tags: wordpress, azure

I'm trying to create a new Wordpress website in Azure.  Today when I get to the page about creating a new mySQL database, I can't check the box to agree to the ClearDB terms - even in the HTML box it's disabled.

Tried this on both US East and US West servers, same thing.  Database name meets their requirements, I've done this a few times in the past.  No idea why I can't today.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

New -> Store

Data -> ClearDB

After that try to add the Wordpress (New -> Compute -> Web Site ->From Gallery), but instead of create a new Mysql database, use this one that you create in the step above.

Answer (score 0):

We getting following error after the step you mentioned.

We cannot provide a billing estimate at this time. Please try again later. If this error persists, contact support with the following information.

Subscription could not be found for the provided subscription id